# Class constant final variable

Tags: java, variables, final, class-constants

This is my code. I need wordOfTheDay and answer to stay the same. I need a user to input an answer for "What is the word of the day" and "What is the answer to 3*8" and depending on their answer it will either be accepted as the correct answer or rejected and they try again.
I keep getting this compiler error

Error: cannot assign a value to final variable wordOfTheDay
Error: cannot assign a value to final variable answer

```
//The word of the day is Kitten 
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SchmeisserKLE41 {

   public static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
   public static final String wordOfTheDay = "Kitten";
   public static final int answer = 24;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int attempts = 3;
     System.out.printf("Please enter the word of the day:");
      wordOfTheDay = input.nextLine();

do{
  -- attempts;
  if(attempts == 0){
    System.out.printf("Sorry! You've exhausted all your attempts!");
    break;
  }
  System.out.printf("Invalid! Try again %d attempt(s) left.", attempts);
  wordOfTheDay = input.nextLine();

}
  while(!wordOfTheDay.equals("Kitten"));


  System.out.printf("\nWhat is the answer to 3 * 8?");
  answer = input.nextInt();

 System.exit(0);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two different variables.  One to store the word of the day, and the other to store the user's guess.  So you'll need to have two different names for them.  Maybe `wordOfTheDay` and `usersGuess`.  Then you can compare them after the user guesses, by changing the condition at the end of your loop to `while(!wordOfTheDay.equals(usersGuess));`

Answer (score 0):

`wordOfTheDay = input.nextLine();` You've already set `wordOfTheDay`. it's final, so you can only set it once....

Comment: How can I keep wordOfTheDay as "Kitten" and test it to see if it it correct of not?

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final String wordOfTheDay = "Kitten";
```

since wordOfTheDay declared as final, it can not be assigned any value after this.

all final variables can not be assigned a value more than once.

so remove final from it as below.

```
public static  String wordOfTheDay = "Kitten";
```

now you can assign value any number of times.

Comment: How can I keep wordOfTheDay as "Kitten" and test it to see if it it correct of not?

Comment: just declared it as non final as shown above and keep assigning value to it on your conditions